# Android: How do I detect if an app is enabled for "allow automatic updating"

Tags: android

I have limited information on the new feature in 2.2: "allow automatic updating" option in the market app.

Is there a way to programmatically detect if an app has enabled "allow automatic updating" option?

I am assuming there's no API to turn on "allow automatic updating" value.

Comment: My gut tells me there's nothing for either of your requests, since that's an Android Market thing, not an Android thing.

Comment: Has this changed at all in later versions of Android?